# About JAXB Databinding in JAX-WS

Tags: data-binding, jaxb

I have developed webservices using CXF framework. We are exposing all our Database operation(Service Layer) methods as a web service methods. We are using Hibernate for persistence.

> For example consider I have one Java POJO class(for hibernate mapping)
>   named CountryEntity.java with the following
>   properties(ID,Name,ModifiedDate).

Inside my service layer i have two methods called

> @WebMethod
>   public CountryEntity createCountryEntity(CountryEntity countryEntity);

```
@WebMethod
public CountryEntity getCountryEntityById(long id);
```

> Based on JAX-WS documentation i understand that it is using JAXB to do
>   the databinding. When user calling my webservice for creating the new
>   Country record i dont want the user to send the Id value and Modified
>   Date value . So what i done is i annotated the propeties(id,modified
>   date) inside the CountryEntity.java with @XmlTransistent annotation.
>   So that operation is working fine.
>
> But when i call getCountryEntityById web service method its returning
>   CountryEntity object but that object dont have the values for ID and
>   Modified Date property. I understand because of XMLTransistent
>   annotation the values not getting Marshalling.
>
> Can i change my method createCountryEntity taking parameters like
>   (String countryName) , so that i no need to include XMLTransistent
>   annotation in my entity classes.? or Anyother solution for this?

Please help me . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no answer i go with parameters instead of sending an object as parameter. Thank you.